# How to call a PostgreSQL stored procedure with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I want to create a Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL to make some calculation and return it to My java call. I have tried Most of the option from Java-Hibernate but not able to succeed. Below is my SP.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GET_REPORT"()
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$DECLARE
      ref refcursor; 
BEGIN
OPEN ref FOR Select sum(balance),avg(balance) from sales;
RETURN ref;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION "GET_REPORT"()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

In Java How to call this procedure to get the values.
NOTE: I'm not using hibernate XML files to call quires.

Please provide Java code(using Session) and any changes in procedure (if required).

Comment: What options have you tried?

Comment: I have tried `session.createStoredProcedureCall`, `session.createSQLQuery` and `session.createStoredProcedureCall`. Not sure whether i need to use Output parameter or return ref cursor is fine.

Comment: Do you want to return the cursor or the value? It seems your function returns cursor.

Comment: Why a `refcursor`? Why not define the function as `returns table (int, int)` and simply use it with `select * from "GET_REPORT"()` (btw: you should _really_ avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers). Or just use a view - your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") can probably better deal with a view, than a function returning a result.

Comment: Query in the above SP is just for an example. I have to make 25 to 30 AGGREGATE function and return it to Java. As I will be using aggregate function from 3 tables I guess no need to create Hibernate entity class.

Comment: @BurakKeceli As i'm new to Hibernate not sure which one to use (cursor or direct values). My final SP will give 25 to 30 aggregate values. If i need to change the SP that also fine for me.

Comment: That still sounds as if you are better off using a view.

Comment: Can you provide any examples for using a view

Comment: `create view sales_report as  Select sum(balance) as average_one, avg(balance) as average_two from sales`. For details please read the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JPA `StoredProcedureQuery` for calling PostgreSQL stored procedures or functions

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("postId", 
        Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("commentCount", 
        Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
    .setParameter("postId", 1L);
 
query.execute();
 
Long commentCount = (Long) query
    .getOutputParameterValue("commentCount");
```

Or, if you want to use the Hibernate `Session`:

```
ProcedureCall call = session
    .createStoredProcedureCall("post_comments");
 
call.registerParameter(1, 
    void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
call.registerParameter(2, 
    Long.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(1L);
 
Output output = call.getOutputs().getCurrent();
 
if (output.isResultSet()) {
    List<Object[]> postComments = 
        ((ResultSetOutput) output).getResultList();
    assertEquals(2, postComments.size());
}
```

That's it!